# How to #include existing header files in Qt?

Tags: qt, header-files

I have some previously written headers and I would like to include them in my Qt project. How can I do that without copying them in place?

After I added them with "Add Existing Files..." I can't seem to be able to #include my headers. Neither #include "header.h" nor #include "fullpath/header.h" works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add an [`INCLUDEPATH`](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#includepath) to your .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += ...
```

Then you can include the header using `#include <...>` syntax (not `"..."`), since then the compiler searches for it in the include path rather than the current working directory which is your project's source folder.

Use the *relative path* of the header *within* your include path, not relative from within your project's source folder.

```
#include <header.h>
```

By the way, adding headers to your project is only needed when they are Qt headers using the Qt meta object system. The ones which define a QObject derived class are passed to the `moc`, this is why a Qt project needs to specify the headers. The real compilation process doesn't need to know which headers are in your project (it just includes them when it sees a `#include` directive).

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarification, too!